# Can't require external react native Components

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm currently trying to learn react Native. While building my first App I tryed to include a external Component from Github (https://github.com/voronianski/react-native-effects-view). Fallowing the small step by step instruction I installed the Component via npm `npm install react-native-effects-view --save` and included the native Code via XCode:

[image]

and required the Component via `var EffectsView = require('react-native-effects-view');`. After restarting the App I get the fallowing error: `Error: Requiring unknown module "react-native-effects-view". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager.` (I did restart the package roughly 1000 times)

Maybe somebody can point out the mistake I did and explain me how to do it correct?

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: Have you done an npm update and then npm install? They are basic steps to do after you install a dependency

Comment: Hi, yes I updated npm and than installed the Component. Sadly it still dons't work

Comment: you need to bundle your app again using run `react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `react-native run-ios`. You need to run this after npm install.

Answer (score 1):

you need to bundle your app again since emulator doesn't have the binary for `react-native-effects-view` module yet

so just run this command again

```
react-native run-ios
```